# How to set one schema for n-1 elements and another for the nth element

Tags: jsonschema

For example, look at the schema:

```
    "type": "array",
    "items":  {
        "oneOf":[
            {"type": "number"},
            {"type": "string"}
        ]
    }
    
}
```

The schema would then allow a list of numbers and the last element would be a string.  and the string can be optional.

For example:

{
"list_of_items" : [ 3, 4, 5, "hello"]
}
is allowed.

{
"list_of_items" : [ 3, "hello" , 4, 5 ]
}
Is not allowed because text is only allowed on the last element.

From reading the documentation.  I see how to do a constant amount of numbers and a text element.
Or all numbers,

But I don't see how to create n-1 numbers and text for the nth.

It could be that is is not something json-schema can do.

Thanks.

Comment: I am fairly certain this is not possible to express with json schema. though it's always possible somebody cleverer than me could think of a way.

Comment: You can get part of the way there - you can say that only one of the items can be a string (with `contains: { type: string }` and `maxContains: 1`), and if the maximum number of total items is small, you can specify all the variants using the array form of `items` plus `oneOf`, but you cannot specify a general case where there are any number of numeric items first and then one string as the last item.

Comment: If changing the data model is an option, JSON Schema can express this constraint if the string is the first element (instead of the last) and the rest of the elements are numbers.

Comment: This is a good argument for a new keyword `postfixItems`. I've created an issue https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/1060 - This does not mean you should wait for this issue to be resolved. There's likely to be a very long lag between this issue and use in production. Jasons above suggestion is your best bet here.